# process.env.proxy no longer populated in React.js in Node 8.8.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I set the proxy in the package.json file like that:

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/"
```

and I used to be able to read the value using

process.env.proxy

Unfortunately since I updated to the latest node v8.8.1 the proxy is no longer part of the process.env properties.

Where did it go and how can I get it?

PS: I need the value because I'm creating links in my UI that point to the API backend.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just require('package.json') and extract it from there.

Comment: Also, if you're using something like Webpack to build your client bundle you can easily include package.json.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the file lives outside the "src" folder and thus cannot be require'd.